# How to migrate an htaccess file from CodeIgniter 3.0.6 to 3.1.6?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a `.htaccess` file that works fine with CodeIgniter version 3.0.6. When I migrate to CodeIgniter version 3.1.6, this htaccess doesn't work and the web page says

> 404 Page Not Found

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|uploads|install|user_guide|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: whats your `php` version?

Comment: https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: @Vickel i'm using php version 5.5.19

Comment: @wolfgang1983 , thanks... but all the htaccess linked above not working for me

Answer (score 1):

your 404 error is most likely not related to your htaccess file, and which you say worked fine before upgrading the CI framework to 3.1.6

as stated in the documents, an upgrade from 3.0.6 to 3.1.6. needs at least  at least PHP 5.6. and in your comment you say to use 5.5.19

check here some details: [Upgrading from 3.0.6 to 3.1.0](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_310.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would put the following into your .htaccess removing the PT flag:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

More information can be found [in the documentation here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html).